# Unable to Understand the Document Size in Mongo Db

Tags: mongodb

I encountered a strange behavior of mongo and I would like to clarify it a bit. I wanted practically find out how many bytes does a single document consume when it has only one boolean attribute present in.

Using Stackoverflow, I found out that I can use the following command

**Object.bsonsize** - some javascript method that should return a size in bytes

While Executing these commands I got some results which is confusing.

Here I provide with the steps I incorporated

1. I Created a Database called **mydatabase** and stored a collection called **datarandom** which has one attribute called **status** and I have set it as **false**.It was assigned an **Object Id=558bf45d5ea9019aec35d7a2**. I ran the following query in RoboMongo

   ```
   Object.bsonsize(db.datarandom.find( {"_id"  :ObjectId("558bf45d5ea9019aec35d7a2")}));
   ```

   I got **100 bytes**.
2. I Ran the second Query on RoboMongo Which is as follows

   ```
   Object.bsonsize(db.datarandom.findOne( {"_id" :ObjectId("558bf45d5ea9019aec35d7a2")}));
   ```

   I got the output as **31 bytes** only!!!!!!

Can Somebody Explain why I am getting two different outputs when I use Find and FindOne when there is only one Document in my Collection with only boolean as an attribute.

Comment: Object.bsonsize(db.datarandom.find( {"_id" :ObjectId("558bf45d5ea9019aec35d7a2")})).. - gives size of the cursor. |  
              Object.bsonsize(db.datarandom.findOne( {"_id" :ObjectId("558bf45d5ea9019aec35d7a2")}))... - gives size of the doc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiples ways to find out the collection size or document size.

In your scenario you inserted only one document with one field `status`, So two fields in one document `_id` and `status`

Use the following command

```
 use mydatabase  //To use particular database

 db.datarandom.stats() //Returns information of datarandom collection
```

`Size` gives the documents size

`Count` gives no of documents, etc.

More details about the collection stats [link](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/reference/collection-statistics/#collStats.size)

### Edit

**Note:**

`find` - which returns cursor object

`Note:` Cursor- A pointer to the result set of a query.

`findOne` - returns particular document, So its gives perfect size of the document without padding space while using with `db.bsonsize`.

`collection.stats()` - Which returns details about the collection, size field gives the document size including padding space.

**Note:** Every document in MongoDB is stored in a record which contains the document itself and extra space, or padding. Padding allows the document to grow as the result of updates while minimizing the likelihood of reallocations.

[Check](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/storage/#record-storage-characteristics) for storage characteristics

#### Big Note

Even though you have only one document or many, `find` and `findone` behavior won't change.

First understand where to use what.

`One question for you`

For example:

```
   [{status: true}] and {status :true}
```

is same?
whether it gives same size?

Comment: hi Karthik, when i ran that command I am getting the Size as 48 bytes. Which is the correct one stats() or object.bsonsize?

Comment: @shubhamagiwal +1 for pointing out, Plz check the edit, Choose the appropriate method based on your requirement

Comment: hi I have only one document in the collection so effectively find and findone should give me the same size. Can you please explain why is there a difference even when find gives a Cursor?

Comment: kudos @karthick.k . This is what i expected.

Answer (score 0):

The [db.collection.find()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) query returns a cursor to the selected document and the [db.collection.findOne()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/) query returns one document, so the sizes are different between a cursor and for one document.

To access the documents with db.collection.find(), you need to iterate over the cursor with .next() or .toArray()

Comment: hi I have only one document in the collection so effectively find and findone  should give me the same size. Can you please explain why is there a difference even when find gives a Cursor?

Comment: "should give the same size" - should? I think not. In one case you get size of a single document. In the other, you're getting size of a *cursor*. You're comparing incomparable things.